# How to get business map location displayed in the right hand sidebar of the Google search results page?

Tags: google-search, google-places

Does anyone know how to get your business map location displayed in the right hand sidebar of the Google search results page? As in the screenshot below:

[image]

I already added my business to this link: http://www.google.co.in/business/placesforbusiness/.

Is adding detail in above link enough or do I need to change my website coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When did you add your business to Google Places? It can take up to 4-5 weeks before the listing could appear in Google's organic search results.

If it has been submitted sometime ago and you still do not have a places map for your listing in the organic search results for a search on your business name, it would be worth linking your Google Places / (now) Google Local listing with your Google Plus business page (now can be linked together also) and verifying your website to the Google Local listing.

Full instructions on how to complete the above steps can be viewed [here](http://435digital.com/blog/2013/04/03/google-places-google-plus-explained/).